# Catch group separated by dashes

Tags: regex

I want to catch a name in a filename that is separated by dashes surrounded by spaces. But the twist is that that name can contain dashes not surrounded by spaces. Here's is an example :

```
My Document - John Doe - English - Whatever.docx
My Document - Marie-Pierre Smith - French - Whatever.docx
```

I want to catch `John Doe` and `Marie-Pierre Smith`.
The names will always be at that position. This is where i'm at so far : https://regex101.com/r/zmIoNQ/2

```
^([\d\w ]*){1} - ([\w ]*){1} - [\d\w -.]*$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use just 1 capturing group to capture the word characters where the hyphen and the word characters that follow are optional. That part can be repeated with a prepended space.

Note that you can omit these quantifiers `{1}`

```
^[\d\w ]*- (\w+(?:-\w+)?(?: \w+(?:-\w+)?)?) -
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EFxeg3/2/)

**Explanation**

- `^[\d\w ]*-` Match chars listed in the charater class from start of string, then match `-`
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `\w+(?:-\w+)?` Match 1+ word chars with an optional group to match `-` follwed by 1+ word chars
  - `(?:` Non capturing

    - `\w+(?:-\w+)?` match a space,  1+ word 
      chars with an optional part that matches a `-` and 1+ word chars
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `)` Close capturing group
- `-` Match space and `-`